# AJAX wrong password login response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've created a simple login form that is posting data to a [fake api](https://reqres.in/) via `$.ajax` jQuery request.

I have 2 questions -

1. How can I set a pair of correct login details to my form
2. How can I show a error response when the incorrect details are logged

```js
$("#my_form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

    $.ajax({
        url: post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data: {
             username: "jordan",
             password: ["miguel"]
        },
    })
    .done(function (response) { 
        $("#server-results").html(response);
    });
});
```

```html
section class="form">
        <h2>Login To Your Account</h2>
        <p class="valid">Valid. Please wait a moment.</p>
        <p class="error">Error. Please enter correct Username &amp; password.</p>
        <form action="https://reqres.in/api/users" class="loginbox" method="post" id="my_login">
            <input placeholder="Username" type="text" id="username"></input>
            <input placeholder="Password" type="password" id="password"></input>
            <button id="submit" value="Submit Form">Login</button>
        <div id="server-results"></div>
        </form>
    </section>
```

Comment: if you're trying to do a login to fake api, put `action="https://reqres.in/api/login"` instead of `/api/users` , replace `username` with `email` and put an email instead, and remove the `[]` from the password.

Comment: for displaying errors, try : `.fail(function(err){console.log(err);})` right after `.done()`

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the square brackets as for the successful login you need to follow the following format according to documentation

```
{
    "email": "email@doamin.com",
    "password": "password"
}
```

but for these credentials you need to create a fake user first

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/register",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        email: "email@domain.com",
        password: "password"
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

on successful registration it will return you token like below with `201 Response`

```
{
    "token": "QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X"
}
```

then to login you can

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://reqres.in/api/login",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            email: "email@domain.com",
            password: "password"
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

if there were no errors the api will return `200 response` with the following json

```
{
    "token": "QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X"
}
```

you can check in your success function for `response.token`.

and to detect if there was any error in login attempt the api returns `400 response` with the following json

```
{
    "error": "Missing password"
}
```

so that means you can use `error:function(response){}`

to show errors hope that helps.

Comment: That makes sense, but I've added this to my code and I have a syntax error. Would've been better to post the final jQuery code all together.

Comment: yeah go ahead , we can sort out what is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data: {
             email: "jordan@example.com", // replace username with email
             password: "miguel" // remove the []
        },
    })
    .done(function (response) { // status code 200
        if(response.error)  // handle wrong email or password ( login errors )
             console.log(response.error);
        else
             $("#server-results").html(response);
    })
    .fail(function(err){ // to handle request errors ( 404, 400, 500 ... )
        console.log(err);
    });
```

and put `https://reqres.in/api/login` in the action of your `form`

Comment: this is not working. It shouldn't be logging in with incorrect data

Comment: not working .. like you have an error or not the response you want ? what part of the data is incorrect ?